Why does Blazor Web App Authentication type Identity, not include the UseAuthorization or UseAuthentication middleware
I have created a Blazor Web App (.NET 8) and selected the Auth type to be "Individiual Authentication". This has scaffolded all of the user management pages for me and provided me the EF models for me to migrate into a database.
However, in the Program.cs file I have noticed a lack of two middleware calls:

UseAuthorization();
UseAuthentication();

Now, I know from ASP.NET you need to include these, and it seems in a lot of the .NET documentation even Blazor tutorials by Microsoft they are included. However, the application with Auth clearly functions without.
My assumption is this is because Blazor Web App uses SignalR instead of HTTP and the token is accessed through the dedicated AuthenticationStateProvider instead of being included in each HTTP request (Which I know doesn't happen in Blazor).
I am just looking for clarification.

In my opinion, inside the new blazor 8 is different than the blazor 7 , the blazor 7 is using the identity default razor page.
Details, you could check Blazor 7' program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

The blazor 8 is using the  identity api endpoint.app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();.
Details, you could check:
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Besides, the source codes contain the code which will add it when the builder class build.
More details, you could refer to this source codes and below codes:
// registering middlewares for services that do not exist
var serviceProviderIsService = _builtApplication.Services.GetService<IServiceProviderIsService>();
if (serviceProviderIsService?.IsService(typeof(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)) is true)
{
    // Don't add more than one instance of the middleware
    if (!_builtApplication.Properties.ContainsKey(AuthenticationMiddlewareSetKey))
    {
        // The Use invocations will set the property on the outer pipeline,
        // but we want to set it on the inner pipeline as well.
        _builtApplication.Properties[AuthenticationMiddlewareSetKey] = true;
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}

if (serviceProviderIsService?.IsService(typeof(IAuthorizationHandlerProvider)) is true)
{
    if (!_builtApplication.Properties.ContainsKey(AuthorizationMiddlewareSetKey))
    {
        _builtApplication.Properties[AuthorizationMiddlewareSetKey] = true;
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
}

